# Nuevo List (Of T) de un Tipo pasado como parametro

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un formulario que recoge información para una tabla en concreto.

Los requerimientos han cambiado y ahora puede recoger de otra tabla. Las tablas tienen exactamente la misma estructura así que quiero aprovechar el formulario para almacenar en ambas tablas.

Sé que podria pasarle el nombre de la tabla al formulario y hacer mis comprobaciones e inserciones pero lo que intento es pasarle el tipo de objeto para usar los métodos y funciones de mis clases.

El tipo lo paso como `Public Property Clase As Type` y el problema lo tengo cuando intento hacer una lista de objetos de dicho tipo `Dim lstResumen As New List(Of Clase)`.

¿Como podría hacer un `List(Of` de un tipo pasado al formulario?.

<sub>Estoy desarrollando en Vb .Net Framework 4.</sub>

Comment: No está muy clara tu pregunta, deberias añadir algun codigo de ejemplo para que podamos ver exactamente lo que intentas. En principio, puedes utilizar métodos genéricos o quizá mejor un interfaz comun, pero sin mas información es dificil aconsejarte bien.

Comment: Nos ayudaría a ayudarte que nos mostrases algo de tu código, aun así has probado a hacer que tu formulario reciba un parámetro de tipo? Así podrías usar ese tipo para crear  la lista.

Comment: Si. Justo mi formulario recibe un parámetro de tipo pero no se como usar ese tipo para crear mi lista.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta, pero en serio te recomendaría utilizar interfaces...

Comment: @JaimeCapilla No me refiero a `Type`si no a un parametro `T`

Answer (score 1):

Para crear una lista a partir de una variable de tipo puedes usar Reflection:

```
Dim listaGenerica As Type = GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(Clase)
Dim a = Activator.CreateInstance(genericList)
```

De todas maneras, no te lo recomiendo. En tu caso, yo creo que lo mejor es, ya que la estructura de las dos clases es la misma, que utilices un Interfaz comun para ambas y te quitaras varios dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías solucionarlo haciendo tu clase genérica de tal modo que se le pase el tipo de parámetro con el que va a trabajar. Un ejemplo sería esto:

```
Public Class FormularioImpostor(Of T)

    Private ListaGenerica As List(Of T)

    Public Sub FormularioImpostor()
       ListaGenerica = New List(Of T)
     End Sub
End Class

Public Class TipoUno
    Public Function Algo()
        Return "asdasdsad"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TipoDos
    Public Function Algo()
        Return "asdasdsad"
    End Function
End Class
```