# Generar propiedad dinámicamente, en base al tipo de objeto recibido

Tags: c#, programación-reactiva

Quiero generar una propiedad en base al tipo de objeto que me llega al ViewModel.

He hecho lo siguiente.

Creado una clase genérica, donde se me genera la propiedad.

```
public class GenericProperty<T>
        {
            public T Property
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

Instancio la clase de la siguiente manera:

```
Type Tipo = Parameter.GetType();
GenericProperty<Tipo> Test = new GenericProperty<Tipo>();
```

Y ahora viene el problema, es que `<Tipo>` me dice:

> Tipo es una variable, pero se usa como tipo

¿Cómo puedo solventar el problema?

Comment: Como es la definición de Parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Ya puse una respuesta similar en [Nuevo List (Of T) de un Tipo pasado como parametro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53342/15301), pero al ser para VB.net no puede considerarse un duplicado.

En realidad, el tipo de un objeto debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación (exceptuando `dynamic` que tiene unos casos de uso muy concretos), con lo que la respuesta a priori sería *no es posible*.

Sin embargo, hay una forma de conseguirlo mediante [`Reflection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Sería algo asi:

```
Type tipo = typeof(GenericProperty<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { Parameter.GetType() });
var Test = Activator.CreateInstance(tipo);
```

Como ves, se hace uso por un lado de [MakeGenericType](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8):

> Sustituye los elementos de una matriz de tipos por los parámetros de tipo de la definición de tipo genérico actual y devuelve un objeto Type que representa el tipo construido resultante.

Y posteriormente de [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8) para crear la instancia del tipo generado:

> Crea una instancia del tipo especificado usando el constructor que mejor coincida con los parámetros especificados.

De todas maneras, como decía en la respuesta enlazada al principio, no se exactamente cual es tu caso de uso pero yo siempre me decantaría por soluciones basadas en interfaces por ejemplo, antes que en recursos de este tipo. Espero aún así que te ayude esta respuesta.

Comment: La respuesta esta genial, pero lo que no termino de entender es, como haciéndolo así, se puede acceder a la propiedad "Property" tipada con el tipo del Param.

Comment: @Diego no se si entiendo tu pregunta. La variable `Test` una vez instanciada usando `CreateInstance` es efectivamente del tipo deseado (`GenericProperty<T>`) exactamente igual que si hicieras por ejemplo `GenericProperty<string> Test = new GenericProperty<string>()`. Por que no ibas a tener acceso a `Property`?